# How to select rows from table when a column repeats?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, count

I have this table (REGIONS) with this sample values:

| Id | Cod1 | Cod2 | Payed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001 | 000A | NULL |
| 2 | 0001 | 000B | YES |
| 3 | 0001 | 000B | YES |
| 4 | 0001 | 000C | NULL |
| 5 | 0001 | 000C | YELL |
| 6 | 0001 | 000D | NULL |
| 7 | 0002 | 000A | YES |
| 8 | 0002 | 000C | NULL |
| 9 | 0002 | 000C | NULL |
| 10 | 0002 | 000C | YES |
| 11 | 0003 | 000C | YES |
| 12 | 0004 | 000C | YES |
| 13 | 0005 | 000A | NULL |
| 14 | 0005 | 000A | YES |
| 15 | 0005 | 000A | NULL |

And I need a select that returns this:

| Cod1 | Cod2 | NumNullPayed | NumYESPayed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | 000A | 1 | 0 |
| 0001 | 000B | 0 | 2 |
| 0001 | 000C | 1 | 1 |
| 0001 | 000D | 1 | 0 |
| 0002 | 000A | 0 | 1 |
| 0002 | 000C | 2 | 1 |

I need to group by Cod1 and Cod2 (and make count of payed at null or yes). BUT ONLY when we have by one Cod1 multiples values for Cod2.

In the previous example, the table has 6 values/row with Cod1 = 0001; and for Cod1= 0001 we have 4 values for Cod2 (A,B,C,D).

Same with cod1 = 0002. But for Cod1 = 0003, Cod2 only has one value (000C), same with 0004 (000C).

And for Cod1 = 0005 we have three rows, BUT ALWAYS with the same Cod2 (000A). So in the select, cod1 = 0003, 0004 and 0005 must be excluded, since they always have the same Cod2.

See the second table.

Comment: This is called conditional aggregation. A quick search will give you a wealth of solutions.

Comment: I know it is conditional aggregation, but I can't think how to do it in the way my boss want

Comment: Then speak to your boss if they don't like the way it's done in the linked duplicate, as they seem to be giving you arbitrary requirements (and we don't know what those arbitrary requirements are).

Comment: The forum you redirect use a thrid column  (prioriy) for the sum. That would help to make the sume of payed in my case. But I don't know how to use Cod1 and Cod2 to group by and also see if they are repeat cod1 with different cod2. I need some help to use those columns in the select clausure and group by clausure.

Comment: *"But I don't know how to use Cod1 and Cod2 to group by"* `GROUP BY Cod1, Cod2`...

Comment: I suggest adding your attempt to the question, the linked duplicate shows you everything you need.

Comment: What I mean is, that the other question will return 15 rows, since in my example will return also the Cod = 0005, but I only need to return when Cod1 is repeat with differents Cod2. I don't see that in the other question. How I check that extra condition? I don't want to group by all cod1-cod2, only by cod1-cod2 when cod1 repeats with diff cod2

Comment: No, I don't want to return Cod1= 0003,0004 and 0005 there: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=670c3774cdbd1ad0184cb9d2270700b4 Because when Cod1 is 0003, 0004 or 0005 is the same Cod2. I only want to select when the same Cod1 has different Cod2

Comment: I'll be more specific: Cod1 = 0003 has only one Cod2 (000C), Cod1 = 0004 has only one Cod2 (000C). Cod1 = 0005 has three values, but always with the same Cod2 (000A). But Cod1 = 0001 or 0002 has differents Cod2 (A,B,C,D) I want to select only those

Comment: So do you need `Cod1 IN ('0001','0002')`. Again, [edit] your post. I have stated that enough times, you aren't making things clearer here..

Comment: No, because it is not only 0001 or 0002, that is only an example. I can't use IN, because can be 0009, 123445 or 6666. I edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter to rows that have one distinct value for `Cod2` first (I use `MIN`/`MAX` as you can't do a windowed `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`) and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT V.Cod1,
           V.Cod2,
           Payed, WHEN MIN(Cod2) OVER (PARTITION BY Cod1) = MAX(Cod2) OVER (PARTITION BY Cod1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS C
    FROM (VALUES(1    ,'0001','000A',NULL),
                (2    ,'0001','000B','YES'),
                (3    ,'0001','000B','YES'),
                (4    ,'0001','000C',NULL),
                (5    ,'0001','000C','YELL'),
                (6    ,'0001','000D',NULL),
                (7    ,'0002','000A','YES'),
                (8    ,'0002','000C',NULL),
                (9    ,'0002','000C',NULL),
                (10   ,'0002','000C','YES'),
                (11   ,'0003','000C','YES'),
                (12   ,'0004','000C','YES'),
                (13   ,'0005','000A',NULL),
                (14   ,'0005','000A','YES'),
                (15   ,'0005','000A',NULL))V(Id,Cod1,Cod2,Payed))
SELECT Cod1,
       Cod2,
       COUNT(CASE Payed WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 END) AS Payed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Payed IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NotPayed
FROM CTE C
WHERE c = 1
GROUP BY Cod1,
         Cod2;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8b6ea05eec48e8b184ac29ea8cc6b61)

Comment: It didn't work, it return 9 rows (instead of 6 rows in the question) with cod1 = 0003, 0004 and 0005

Comment: Missed out the `WHERE` predicate in my paste, apologies, @Keras-JOB .

Comment: Thanks my friend it works!! I wander if you could explain a little the query xD. Why do you use WITH CTE AS( and this part: "WHEN MIN(Cod2) OVER (PARTITION BY Cod1) = MAX(Cod2) OVER (PARTITION BY Cod1) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS C" what exactly do? And what means WHERE c = 1? Sorry if this are dumb questions

Comment: From the answer, @Keras-JOB *"Filter to rows that have one distinct value for Cod2 first (I use MIN/MAX as you can't do a windowed COUNT(DISTINCT...)) "* If the `MIN` and the `MAX` is the same, they have *1* value.